# How to get contacts numbers from phone in fragment android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-contacts

In my application I want to display all the contacts numbers from the phone. I wrote the code. But it is not working. Please any one help me out. 
This is my code:

```
public class MobileFragment extends Fragment{
    iv_contacts = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.iv_contacts);
    ic_contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            browseContacts();
        }
    });
}

private void browseContacts() {
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
    pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only

    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {  
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {    
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();    
            String[] projection = { Phone.NUMBER };
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
            int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = cursor.getString(column);
            number = number.replace(" ", "");   
        }
    }
}
```

Here my onActivity result is not calling in my fragment.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: k i will showmy code. please help me out. i am trying this from 0ne week

Comment: please any one help me out

Comment: please any one reply me...please help me out

Comment: I think i am late but do you have OnActivityResult in your activity as well ?